# API Service Base64Encode Not Accepting Files more than 5mb

Tags: api, upload

I have written a API Service, but that's not Accepting Files more than 5mb,
Here i am sharing my Code Snippet please tell me whats the issue.

**Code:**

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SympRESTApi/*')
global with sharing class OCRServiceAPI
{
@HttpGet
global static string GetIfwData()
{
    string IfwId='';
    if(Schema.sObjectType.Ifw_Data_v1__c.isAccessible())
    {
        List<Ifw_Data_v1__c> objIfwData=[SELECT Id, Name FROM Ifw_Data_v1__c limit 1];
        IfwId = objIfwData[0].Id;
    }
    return IfwId;
}

@HttpPost
global static string UploadPDF(string PdfContent, string PdfFileName, string IfwRecordId)
{
    string Res='{"Result" : "failed"}';
    try
    {
        if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isCreateable())
        {
            ContentVersion ContVer = new ContentVersion();
            string jsonStr =PdfContent;
            if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.fields.versionData.isCreateable())
            ContVer.versionData = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(jsonStr);
            if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.fields.title.isCreateable())
            ContVer.title = PdfFileName;
            if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.fields.pathOnClient.isCreateable())
            ContVer.pathOnClient =PdfFileName;
            if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isCreateable()) 
            insert ContVer;
            system.debug('Content Document-->>>:::'+ContVer);

            if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentVersion.isAccessible())
            {
                ContentVersion ConVer=[Select Id, ContentDocumentId from ContentVersion Where Id =:ContVer.Id];

                ContentDocumentLink ObjContLink=new ContentDocumentLink();

                if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentDocumentLink.fields.ContentDocumentId.isCreateable())
                ObjContLink.ContentDocumentId=ConVer.ContentDocumentId;
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentDocumentLink.fields.LinkedEntityId.isCreateable())
                ObjContLink.LinkedEntityId=IfwRecordId;
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentDocumentLink.fields.ShareType.isCreateable())
                ObjContLink.ShareType='V';
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentDocumentLink.fields.Visibility.isCreateable())
                ObjContLink.Visibility='AllUsers';
                if(Schema.sObjectType.ContentDocumentLink.isCreateable()) 
                insert ObjContLink;
                system.debug('Content Document link-->>>:::'+ObjContLink);

                if(Schema.sObjectType.Ifw_Data_v1__c.isAccessible() && Schema.sObjectType.Ifw_Data_v1__c.isUpdateable())
                {
                    Ifw_Data_v1__c ifw = [SELECT Id,OCR_File_Name__c FROM Ifw_Data_v1__c WHERE id=:IfwRecordId LIMIT 1];
                    if(Schema.sObjectType.Ifw_Data_v1__c.fields.OCR_File_Name__c.isUpdateable())
                    ifw.OCR_File_Name__c= ObjContLink.Id;
                    if(Schema.sObjectType.Ifw_Data_v1__c.isUpdateable()) 
                    Update ifw;
                    system.debug('Content Document IFW Data-->>>:::'+ifw);       
                    Res = '{"Result" : "success"}';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Res= '{"Result" : "' + ex.getMessage() + '"}';
    }
    return Res;
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Keep in mind that heap size is 6 mb for single execution context

Comment: okay. in salesforce we can upload a document upto 2GB right ? but why my code is unable to process a file.can you please give me any workaround or Example for this ?

Comment: It is possible to upload files bigger then 2 gb using VF and JS (with chatter component) -- https://hub.appirio.com/tech-blog/upload-a-file-as-large-as-2gb-in-salesforce-using-a-visualforce-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is because of the parameter `string PdfContent`. As you have this declared as String, that's where it's not allowing you to upload a content of more than 5 MB.

If you refer to the String [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_primitives.htm), it mentions that there's no limit of how many characters can a String hold (excerpt below):

> String size: Strings have no limit on the number of characters they
>   can include. Instead, the [**heap size limit**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) is used to ensure that your
>   Apex programs don't grow too large.

However, if you follow the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm), you will see that within the Apex transaction context, the *Total heap size is 6 MB*.

This is where anything coming in through which is more than the allowable heap size results in failures.

As for your alternatives, you can review the standard REST APIs with which you can upload files of larger sizes. Reference links below:

- [Inputs and Binary File Upload Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)
- [Insert or Update Blob Data](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_sobject_insert_update_blob.htm)